# How to rotate ip address of each request from same machine

Tags: java, linux, networking

My requirement is to rotate ip address for each http requests originating from single machine. Is it possible to control IP of each request at application level assuming I have a set of registered IP addresses with me ?

Thanks

Jitendra

Answer (score 0):

Sure, all you have to do it to bind the socket to the address you want to use. See [`Socket::bind(SocketAddress)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#bind%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) and [`SocketFactory::createSocket(InetAddress, int, InetAddress, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html#createSocket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29).

You most likely want to use a library to do the request; you'll have to find a way to specify e.g. the `SocketFactory` the library will use (or it may already accept a local address).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please explain in little detail, how can we use this socket when fetching a page using URLConnection or HttpClient.